# Why do I get random values when the initializer value is set to a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, save, restore

In TensorFlow when storing and restoring variables using tf.train.Saver I get random values when the initializer value is set to a tensor, why?

I have two ways of creating a variable, one that initializes using a function and the other with a tensor:

```
# Way 1, works when restoring
T = tf.get_variable('T', shape=[3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
# Way 2-a, doesn't work when restoring
T = tf.get_variable('T', initializer = [1,2,3]) # Doesn't restore
# Way 2-b
T = tf.Variable(name='T', initial_value=[1,2,3]) # Doesn't restore
# Way 2-c
T = tf.Variable(name='T', initial_value=tf.constant([1,2,3])) # Doesn't restore
```

When I try to restore the variable using the second way, the values seem randomly generated.

I created a Jupyter Notebook to see the problem in action (you don't need to do anything but press enter): https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QoJ_YFYZQe3GSAi3Lr7wOnsnt2jCjPR7 .

Am I missing something? Why does this happen? Is it a bug?
It all seems counterintuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`tf.constant_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant_initializer):

```
T = tf.get_variable('T', shape=[3], 
                    initializer=tf.constant_initializer([1,2,3]))
```

From the docs on [`tf.get_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable):

> The initializer can also be a Tensor, in which case the variable is initialized to this value and shape.

So you may also be able to get by with setting it to an explicit Tensor, in which case you do not need to pass a shape. Something like:

```
T = tf.get_variable('T', initializer=tf.constant([1,2,3]))
```

I think the issue arises from passing a list instead of a tensor, although typically TF automatically converts array-likes to Tensors, so that to me is a bit weird.

Comment: Yep, that works. Do you know if there's some reason for the other way no to work?

Comment: @loco.loop updated with some new stuff I learned. I think you just have to pass an initializer object or a tensor, not a list. Looking into why you can't pass a list...

Comment: yep but check way 2-c, it uses a tensor.

Comment: But way 2-c isn't using `get_variable`, it's just creating a variable. If you want to restore an existing variable, use `get_variable`.

Comment: These are all ways to create a variable, the problem I have it when restoring them... when I create them in way 2-* retoring their values doesn't work. Check the link that I posted, it a Jupyter notebook that shows the problem in action.

Comment: Did you run `tf.global_variables_initializer()` in the 2-* cases? I can't open your notebook, I think it's some proxy issue on my end...